# Update XML element with LINQ to XML

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I'm editing XML element with the following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Test XML with LINQ to XML-->

<LabSerivceInfo>

  <LabService>
    <ServiceType>Copy</ServiceType>
    <Price>1</Price>
  </LabService>

  <LabService>
    <ServiceType>PrintBlackAndWhite</ServiceType>
    <Price>2</Price>
  </LabService>

</LabSerivceInfo>

Dim varServiceType = txtServiceType.Text.Trim
```

How to update the ServiceType and Price where ServiceType = varServiceType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Dim el = (From x In doc.XPathSelectElements("//*") _
          Where x.Value = varServiceType _
          Select x.Parent).FirstOrDefault()
```

The above code returns the `<LabService>` element.

**Edited to add:**

> Hey, I can select the Price like this with condition
>
> ```
> Dim query = (From s In xElement.Load(theXMLSource1).Descendants("LabService") _
>             Where s.Element("ServiceType") = "Scan" _
>             Select s.Element("Price").Value).FirstOrDefault()
> ```
>
> But, I can't figure it out how to update it yet. Can you share some code on this?

Using your sample:

```
Dim price = (From s In xElement.Load(theXMLSource1).Descendants("LabService") _
            Where s.Element("ServiceType") = "Scan" _
            Select s.Element("Price")).FirstOrDefault() 

price.Value += 1500
```

Comment: Hey, I can select the Price like this with condition             Dim query = (From s In xElement.Load(theXMLSource1).Descendants("LabService") Where s.Element("ServiceType") = "Scan" Select s.Element("Price").Value).FirstOrDefault

But, I can't figure it out how to update it yet. Can you share some code on this?

Answer (score 1):

Check these out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688087.aspx
"LINQ to XML Samples" ~~ vb

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387091.aspx
"Samples (LINQ to XML)" ~~ c# and vb

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397965.aspx
"LINQ C# Samples"

more:  via Google:

```
linq to xml samples
```